# Avoid image and headers from moving out of place when the page shrinks CSS

Tags: html, css

Good morning. I am kind of new to CSS and I was wondering if someone can tell me how to stop the contents of my header from moving all over the place when I shrink the page and from merging on top of each other. I looked it up online,but I still have not been able to figure it out. Thanks

HTML

```
<header id= "top">
            <div id="title"><h1>Jorge </h1></div>
             <div id="quote"><h6></br></br>quote here
             <br/><br/>anonymous</h6></div>
            <div id="pic">
                <a href="resume.pdf"><img src="images/one.jpg" title="See resume" height=250px align="middle"/></a>
            </div>

        </header>
```

CSS

```
h1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font: bold 35px tahoma;
    text-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.8) 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 400px;
}
h6{

    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}
#pic{

    float: right;
    border:3px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;

}

#pic:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    background: #1ec7e6;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing some css would help greatly, or maybe a jsfiddle example but if you are trying to design a responsive layout then you want to use percentages and not fixed widths

Without seeing any css or what you are wanting this to actually look like I cannot tell what is going on "moving all over the place" is not very specific.

To stop things from dropping under each other try using `float: left;` on the elements or `display: inline;` on the parent

try this:

```
h1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font: bold 35px tahoma;
    text-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.8) 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left
}
h6{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    float: right;
}

#pic{
    float: right;
    border:3px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110,.6) 5px 5px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, background 1s;
}

#pic:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    background: #1ec7e6;
}
```

Comment: I apologize. I had pasted the CSS code and I apparently erased it before submitting. here it is. @SimonStaton

Comment: The headers are shrinking now, but are causing the picture to move all over the place. I want the text to stay fix and disappear as you shrink the page. Same for the picture.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the original question so was not added, if you are wanting an element to disappear on resizing you will need to use JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this out [960 grid system](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://960.gs/&ei=01gfUoeAEK7iigLeiYDYBw&usg=AFQjCNG7o9W1K2PN56W6QumHlshaE6Kq7g&sig2=7FtmMi17tZeoM4K_GliRvw&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cGE). Makes resizing pages a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some things hidden at different page widths, look into [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). These let you define CSS rules that apply at different conditions, usually page width (but could also be things like device orientation or capabilities). For example, if you wanted to hide your pic on small screens, you might do something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #pic {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

What this tells the browser is, "When you're less than 768 pixels wide, use the following rules; otherwise, ignore them."